# Endless redirect loop after ticket validation

Tags: validation, tomcat, filter, liferay, cas

I'm using the Liferay Portal 6.1.1 CE GA2.
After hours of research I got the following things to work:

- Import from a LDAP-Server and custom mapping of an attribute to an usergroup.
- Redirect to a specific page after login (based on the usergroup).
- Authentication via CAS. This means getting a ServiceTicket and logging in the corresponding user.

Now I'm trying to obtain ProxyTickets so I can proxy to other applications behind the same CAS-Server.

I'm not really getting any error, but Mozilla gives me a redirection error, e.g. the page is redirected in such a way that it can never be loaded.
I googled a lot and tried different approaches but nothing helped.

My web.xml is configured as follows (I snipped out urls. If they're important I can hand them in later):

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>* snip */cas/login</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>serverName</param-name>
    <param-value>* snip *</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
  <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
    <param-value>* snip */cas/</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>serverName</param-name>
    <param-value>* snip *</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>proxyCallbackUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>https://* snip */pgtCallback</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>proxyReceptorUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>/pgtCallback</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/c/portal/login</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I tried various combinations of the `filter-mappings` but nothing helped.

The output of the console in Eclipse hints that multiple consecutive requests are done. Each gets me a `TGT`, `PGTIOU` and `PGT` but after the `ST` is validated a new validation request is fired. This goes until Mozilla ends the redirect loop.

I also tried specifying `service` instead of `serverName` but all remains the same.
Setting the param `redirectAfterValidation` to `false` but then I get a `MalformedURLException`.

Hopefully I didn't forget any information, please help me.

Thanks in advance.